# Dynamic page creation PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, dynamic

Been struggling with this problem for a while now and I just can't het my brain to understand it.

I have a very simple website where I can add items in a database. There is a list on index.php where the list is displayed and each item needs a url that directs to a "more information" page.

The "more information" page has to be a dynamic one as there are a lot of items and these items can be added or deletend.

What my code for this section looks like at the moment:

```
$result_set = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM items WHERE id = $item");
while ($item = mysql_fetch_row($result_set)) {
$name = $item['name'];
echo "<a href=\"/items/".$item['1'].".html\">$name</a>";
```

This results in a link if item 1 = wrench ../items/wrench.html.

But this page obviously doesn't excist. How can I get this to work?

Comment: i guess you need this echo `"<a href=\"/items/".$item['name'].".html\">$name</a>";`

Comment: I feel like I have to warn you about using mysql_* even if that itself is not the problem here.

Comment: You should be using prepared statements, it helps mitigate the risk of SQL injection attacks. It's just as easy, it just seems as though most tutorials online use mysql_x which is depricated. Seriously, do yourself this favor it's no good learning bad habbits early on. See: php.net/pdo and php.net/mysqli

Comment: Could you EDIT your question to show valid URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use .htaccess for this.
you can add this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^items/(.+)$ items.php?page=$1
```

In your items.php use $items=$_GET[page]; so you can read what is in url after items/

This is a link where you can find more about RewriteRule's http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: I think OP will like this, but I assume it may be over his head. I think the question was geared more towards 'how do i create a dynamic page based on GET parameters' -- The question is worded poorly.

Comment: if you wote down than be more specific about question so we can help. did not write to you David Houde :)

Comment: I'd like this, but I can't figure out how this works. What is the $1.

Comment: $1 is not important so much, David Houde is explain that. on your items.php use $items=$_GET[page]; so you can read what is in url after items/

Comment: $1 represents the 'item' -- So a request for /items/wrench.php will really be seen by /items.php?page=wrench -- You will still need to create item.php which will use $_GET['page'] to query the database and pull the additional information.

Comment: So what I will have on the index.php is <a     href=\"/items/index.php?".$item['1'].".html\">$name</a> and on the items.php I will have the  $items=$_GET[page];

Comment: you will not use index.php?item[1].html you will use /items/nice-book.html in url and <a href=/items/".$item[name].".html>$item[name]</a> as a link

Comment: I got it to work! I forgot to put page in ../items/items.php?page.$item[1]... Thanks for the help! Really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can't have one html page for each item if the items are dynamically added
But you can do it this way

```
 echo '<a href="/items/more_information.php?item_id='.$item['1'].' ">$name</a>';
```

This way you have only one page who receive as a GET parameter the id of the item you want the description.
In the page of more_information.php you just display a text corresponding to the id you received.